# Parameter equals none if not specified powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to pass various parameters to a PowerShell script, however if no value is passed that script exits with an error. For example:

```
.powershellscript.ps1 -path C:\test -Name text.txt -Date 20111212
```

Works fine, however if I execute:

```
.powershellscript.ps1 -path C:\test -Name text.txt -Date
```

I receive the following error

> "Missing an argument for parameter 'Date'. Specify a parameter
>   of type 'System.Object' and try again."

I want to be able to assign the Date value to $Null if it's not passed through the script.

Inside the .powershellscript.ps1, the parameters is handled as:

```
param(
    $path,
    $Name,
    $Date
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to pass a value for `$Date` call the script like this:

```
.powershellscript.ps1 -path C:\test -Name text.txt
```

`$Date` should then be `$null` in your script.

Comment: Is there a way whereby the -Date parameter is kept?

Comment: `.powershellscript.ps1 -path C:\test -Name text.txt -Date $null`. If you have -Date in there then PowerShell will expect you to provide an argument for it. So either miss it our or pass in `$null`.